# Правильная структура базы данных отправки товара

Tags: mysql, база-данных, phpmyadmin, архитектура

У меня есть товар - "Ассорти овощей", в который входит множество категорий, то есть помидоры и огурцы.
Структура:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И у меня есть еще один товар, назовем "Овощ" (таблица - Товар) у которого может быть только 1 категория (таких записей с одиночными категориями будет много).

Нужно ли для этого создавать новые две таблицы "ТоварОвощи" И "ЗаказОвощи"? При условие что записи не совсем будут связаны с этой таблицей. Или просто в товар поставить поле типа `bool` к примеру, и различать относится ли он к одиночной или множественной категории (это важно) - и занести также в "ТоварКатегории"

P.S прошу простить если непонятно объяснил. Спрашивайте - разъясню подробнее.

Comment: Не надо НИЧЕГО. Какая разница, одна категория или десять у конкретного экземпляра сущности? На структуру это не влияет, связь как была 1:N, так и осталась. А надо будет - запросом получишь количество категорий для конкретного товара, и от полученного значения (единица или больше) будешь плясать.

Comment: Меня смущает просто, что к этим определенным записям (где только 1 категория должна быть), еще могут привязываться категории. Понятное дело, что это можно все ограничить на сервере, но все же.

Comment: *Понятное дело, что это можно все ограничить на сервере* Не можно, а нужно. При этом должна существовать дополнительная таблица, либо поле в текущей таблице, где проставляется признак "только одна категория", и на основании этих данных запрос на добавление второй категории будет отвергаться.